# REPLACE function not working in User Defined Function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

TSQL REPLACE function works in query analyzer, but does nothing when inside a user defined function.

Checked COLLATION: SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS on the database and column.
Selected the field from a query, and put it in a hex editor, and sure enough, it's a bunch of ascii spaces, x'20'.

WORKS:

```
declare  @HTMLText varchar(MAX) = '   Normal      Wi-Fi Enabled &ndash; Does the bus provide a Wi-Fi enabled connection?'

WHILE (@HTMLText like '%  %') 
   BEGIN
      set @HTMLText = REPLACE(@HTMLText, '  ', ' ')
   END
```

I expect all double spaces to be squeezed out of the resulting string.  But it isn't.

Comment: Can you show the UDF as that's where it failing. `select cast(F as varbinary(max)) from T where id = X` will allow you to look at the bytes in-situ as a double check.

Comment: If you want to replace multiple spaces with one there is a much better approach than using loops here. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/replace-multiple-spaces-with-one

Comment: @AlexK. HOLY SMOKES!  You're brilliant! '0D 0A 20 0D 0A 20 0D 0A 20'  Cut and pasting the results for testing was jacking with the data!

Comment: @SeanLange, thank you for the link, but that too fails in this case.

Comment: What do you mean it fails in this case? Where is the function code? We can't help you unless you provide us the details.

Comment: No, thank you both for the suggestions.  I think it has put me on a new path.  It looks as though there is strange non-printable characters in the source data.  I've not figured out why it was working in query analyzer and not in the function, but I am looking into the data now.  Instead of showing two hex 20s, viewing the data as binary showed the above mentioned x'0D 0A 20 0D 0A 20'  (For the record, not my database, not my data!)  This table is storing formatted text, rather than actual data.

Comment: OK, I'm going to assume the Query Analyzer worked because doing a cut and past into a variable for testing made changes to the data.  The reason it wasn't working in against the table was that the data in the table had non-printable characters.  To further complicate matters, the column (defined as varchar) had been populated from another table/column defined as NVARCHAR.  I used a bit from both suggestions to clean it up, but now I'm thinking rather than clean it when I pull it out of the table, I need to clean the table itself.  Thanks to you both for taking a bit of your time to help me.

Comment: @ARLibertarian x0D + x0A is a line break, the following x20 a blank. If it really looks like this, your data is not `NVARCHAR`, otherwise it was `x000D000A0020` I think, your data is not what you think it is...

Comment: Thanks for that!  I was about to look those up in the ascii table this morning.  CHR(10) and CHR(13).  Of course it would be.  I don't usually think in HEX.  I'm used to dealing with NAME, ADDRESS, DESCRIPTION, not whole chunks of web pages stored in a database.

Comment: @SeanLange, I used your suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have written double space I guess. Following code works

```
declare  @HTMLText varchar(MAX) = '   Normal      Wi-Fi Enabled &ndash; Does the bus provide a Wi-Fi enabled connection?'

   set @HTMLText = REPLACE(@HTMLText, ' ', '')
   SELECT @HTMLText
```

Comment: It works in my query analyzer, but when I include it as part of a user defined function, it does not.  Like wise, set @HTMLText = REPLACE(@HTMLText, 'EN-US', '') is not working from within the function.

Comment: Sure, it's below.  Once I actually LOOKED at the data in HEX, it became obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned it up somewhat by adding 
         set @HTMLText = REPLACE(@HTMLText, 0x0D,'')
         set @HTMLText = REPLACE(@HTMLText, 0x0A,'') 
to my function.

I would not have seen the odd data if Alex had not pointed me in the direction of viewing the data as binary.  It has been pointed out that these are chr(13) and chr(10), which I'm more familiar with. DOH.

Thanks to everyone who took the time.